# Scala merge between 2 lists base on condition

Tags: list, scala

So i have this 2 `Lists`:

```
val names = ListBuffer[(String, Double)]
names += ("Nat", 11.0)
names += ("Dan", 12.2)
names += ("Jeen", 0)
names += ("David", 55.0)

val list2 = ListBuffer[(String, Boolean)]
list2 += ("Nat", false)
list2 += ("Dan", true)
list2 += ("Jeen", false)
list2 += ("David", false)
```

So i want new `List` with all the names that are equal to `"Dan"` with value > 0, and value is `true` so in my example this should return `List` with 1 element:

```
"Dan", 12.2
```

Comment: C# answer: `names.Where(x => x.Item2 > 0).Join(list2.Where(y => y.Item2), x => x.Item1, y => y.Item1, (x, y) => x).Where(x => x.Item1 == "Dan");` Or something like, `names.Concat(list.Select(y => new { y.name, value = Convert.ToDouble(y.condition) })).GroupBy(x => x.name).Where(x => x.Key == "Dan" && x.All(y => y > 0)).First();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
names
  .zip(list2.map(_._2))
  .filter(_._2)
  .map(_._1)
  .filter(_._2 > 0)
```

The `zip` combines the names list with the true/false value from the second list (I have assumed your `list2` is ordered the same way as `names`, as shown in your example, so therefore we can drop the name in `list2` with a `map` to just retrieve the boolean). This results in a List like:

`ListBuffer(((Nat,11.0),false), ((Dan,12.2),true), ((Jeen,0.0),false), ((David,55.0),false))`

Now we filter on the true/false value (`_._2`), resulting in a list like:

`ListBuffer(((Dan,12.2),true))`

Now we don't need the boolean any more, so drop it to leave us with a list of name-value tuples via `map(_._1)`, resulting in:

`ListBuffer((Dan,12.2))`

and then lastly we filter where value is `> 0` with `.filter(_._2 > 0)`, which in your example still leaves us a List with the same contents (try changing `Jeen` to `true` to see this last filter in action):

`ListBuffer((Dan,12.2))`